# What is the prototype of the String constructor function (String.__proto__)?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
var mString = new String('A');

console.log(typeof mString); // object

console.log(mString instanceof String); // true

console.log(mString instanceof Object); // true

console.log(mString.__proto__ === String.prototype); // true

console.log(mString.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
```

Now, why

```
console.log(String.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // true
```

and not

```
console.log(String.__proto__ === Object.prototype); // false
```

when walking up the prototype chain?

What is between String and Object prototypes?

Comment: Between a *String instance* and the *Object prototype* is the *String prototype*

Comment: Don't use the deprecated `.__proto__` getter. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
Function.prototype === String.__proto__ //true
```

It's a function's prototype, because String is a constructor function.

Comment: Its also worth noting that this is true for all classes not just String. For example `(class A {}).__proto__ === Function.prototype` is true

Comment: Because classes are just syntactic sugar over function constructors.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `instanceof Object` it means that the variable is either an `Object` or "extends" an `Object`.

As mentioned [here](http://%60instanceof%60%20doesn't%20mhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) *"The instanceof operator tests whether the prototype property of a constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object."*

So `mString.__proto__` is not equal to `Object.prototype`, but it `Object.prototype` is indeed higher on the prototype chain, that's why they are not equal. The String prototype inherits the Object prototype.